# Regex match ; but not \;

Tags: java, regex, split

```
MID4BNW2Uq-01;Standard Offline - Acc 01;SA\;BATE:GOOGN
```

I'm trying to split the above line on semicolons like so:
`line.split(";", -1)`.

The resulting list that I need is:

```
1. MID4BNW2Uq-01
2. Standard Offline - Acc 01
3. SA\;BATE:GOOGN
```

But instead, I get one more element because of that `";"` inside `SA\;BATE:GOOGN`:

```
1. MID4BNW2Uq-01
2. Standard Offline - Acc 01
3. SA\
4. BATE:GOOGN
```

I'm looking for a way to make the .split method match `";"` BUT NOT `"\;"`.
In other words, split on the semicolon (;) only if there's no "\" right before it.

I've thought about using regex but I'm at a complete loss when it comes to it.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: split("[^\\]?") maybe? Not entirely sure about Java regex syntax, but it should be like this.

Comment: I've tried it but I get a red squiggly line saying "Illegal escape character in string literal"

Comment: @GeorgeCimpoies work with `(?<!\\);` or `(?<!\\\\);` ? If second one you may accept my answer ^^

Comment: It is much safer to *match* using [`String pat = "(?s)(?:[^;\\\\]|\\\\.)+";`](https://regex101.com/r/9plWhS/1) pattern.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include an answer. If you have found a solution that wasn't proposed by any of the other answers feel free to add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a zero-length assertion called "[negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)".

For example,

```
(?<!a)b
```

matches a "b" that is not preceded by an "a", using negative lookbehind.

Try splitting on this:

```
(?<!\\);
```

The backslash is a special character in regular expressions so it must be escaped using an extra backslash.

Comment: It won't work if there is a literal backslash before `;`.

Comment: If that's a requirement he needs to add another negative lookbehind assertion for that.

Comment: Just a lookbehind or two won't help here.

Comment: Also need to double escape, pattern like this give : PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 7

Comment: Works for me using Java 8.